The angle bisectors of triangle ABC intersect at point I and CA + AI = BC. Find $\frac{\angle BAC}{\angle CBA}$.
Problem: the angle bisectors of triangle $ABC$ intersect at point $I$. It is known that $CA + AI = BC$. Find the ratio of angles $BAC$ and $CBA$.
What I tried: if we reflect the point $B$ relative to line $IC$ and get point $B'$ then $AI = AB'$ and the triangle $B'BC$ is equilateral. But it didn't help.
What I know:

It's a problem in theme "additional construction"
Probably it's from some school olympiad, Slovenia, 2005


Use coordinate geometry

Construct point $D$ on $CB$ such that $CD=CA$ and consequently $BD=AI$.
Let lines $AD$ and $BI$ intersect at $O$; it is not difficult to show that triangles $BDO$ and $AIO$ are congruent, because
$$
\angle OAC=90°-{1\over2}\angle ACB={1\over2}\angle BAC+{1\over2}\angle ABC
$$
and
$$\angle OAI=\angle OAC-\angle IAC={1\over2}\angle ABC=\angle OBD.$$
It follows that triangle $BOA$ is isosceles and $\angle OAB=\angle OBA$, whence $\angle ABC=\angle BAI={1\over2}\angle BAC$.


Thank you very much!

Call $\angle BAC = 2\alpha$, $\angle CBA = 2\beta$ and $\angle BCA = 2\gamma$, hence $\gamma = \pi /2 - \alpha - \beta$, using law of sines in triangle $AIC$ and in $ABC$ we have
\begin{align*}
&\frac{CA}{\sin{(\alpha+\gamma)}} = \frac{AI}{\sin{\gamma}} \\
&\frac{CA}{\sin{2\beta}} = \frac{BC}{\sin{2\alpha}}
\end{align*}
hence
\begin{align*}
&AI =\frac{CA\sin{\gamma}}{\sin{(\alpha+\gamma)}} \\
&BC = \frac{CA\sin{2\alpha}}{\sin{2\beta}}
\end{align*}
plugging this into $CA+AI = BC$ and using $\gamma = \pi /2 - \alpha - \beta$  we have
\begin{align*}
&CA + \frac{CA\sin{\gamma}}{\sin{(\alpha+\gamma)}} = \frac{CA\sin{2\alpha}}{\sin{2\beta}} \\
& 1+\frac{\sin{\gamma}}{\sin{(\alpha+\gamma)}} = \frac{\sin{2\alpha}}{\sin{2\beta}} \\
& 1+ \frac{\cos{(\alpha+\beta)}}{\cos{\beta}} = \frac{\sin{2\alpha}}{\sin{2\beta}} \\
& \frac{\cos{(\alpha+\beta)}}{\cos{\beta}} = \frac{\sin{2\alpha}-\sin{2\beta}}{\sin{2\beta}} = \frac{2\sin{(\alpha-\beta)\cos{(\alpha+\beta)}}}{2\sin{\beta}\cos{\beta}} \\
& \sin{\beta} = \sin{(\alpha - \beta)}
\end{align*}
So either $\beta = \alpha - \beta$ and hence $\alpha = 2\beta$ or $\beta = \pi - \alpha+ \beta$ which would imply $\alpha = \pi$, but $2\alpha < \pi$, so we must have the first choice, hence
$$
\frac{\angle BAC}{\angle CBA} = \frac{2\alpha}{2\beta} = \frac{\alpha}{\beta} = 2.
$$

Thank you very much!

$CA+AI=BC$ can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{r}{\tan\frac C2}+\frac{r}{\tan\frac A2}+\frac{r}{\sin\frac A2}=
\frac{r}{\tan\frac C2}+\frac{r}{\tan\frac B2},
$$
where $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circle.
From this one obtains
$$
\frac{1}{\tan\frac B2}=\frac{1}{\tan\frac A2}+\frac{1}{\sin\frac A2}
=\frac{1}{\tan\frac A4}\implies A=2B.
$$

Thank you very much!
